# Auto Generate Identity Column in C# Net Core 3.1 Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit.net, in-memory-database

My basic classes

```
    public class Book {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set;} 
    }
    public class Author {
        public Author () {
            BookList = new HashSet<Book> ();
            for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
                var book = new Book() {
                    Title = "Funny book" + i;
                }
                BookList.Add(book);
            }
        }
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public ICollection<Book> BookList { get; set; }
    }
```

My repository classess

```
        public interface IBookRepository
    {       
        Task<Book> CreateBook(Book book);
    }
    public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
    {
        public BookRepository(BookStoreContext context)
             : base(context)
        {
        }
        public async Task<Book> CreateBook(Book book)
        {
            if (book == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("book cannot be null");
            }
            Context.Book.Add(book);
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return book;
        }           
    }
```

I am setting up my Unit Test with the following utility class

```
    public static class AuthorData
    {
        public static List<Author> GetData()
        {
            List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
            Author author1 = new Author()
            {
                Id = 100,
                Name="author1"
            };
            authors.Add(author1);
            Author author2 = new Author()
            {
                Id = 200,
                Name="author2"
            };
            authors.Add(author2);
        }
    }
    public static class BookData
    {
        public static List<Book> GetData()
        {
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
            Book book1 = new Book()
            {
                Id = 1000,
                Name="Wonderful book 1"
            };
            books.Add(book1);
            Book book2 = new Book()
            {
                Id = 1001,
                Name="Wonderful book 2"
            };
            books.Add(book2);
        }
    }
      public class AuthorContextMock
      {
         public static BookStoreContext ConfigureSensorContext(IServiceCollection services)
          {
            services.AddDbContext<BookStoreContext>(c =>
         c.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)
        .EnableDetailedErrors()
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
         var serviceProvider = services
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
         var Context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BookStoreContext>();
         Context.Database.EnsureCreated();

         Context.Authors.AddRange(AuthorData.GetData());
         Context.Books.AddRange(BookData.GetData());
         Context.SaveChanges();
         return Context;
        }
    }
```

My unit test

```
[Fact]
    public async Task CreateBookTest()
    {       
        var context = BookContextMock.ConfigureBookContext(new ServiceCollection());
        BookRepository repo = new BookRepository(context);
        Book book = new BookSensor()
        {
            Title = "New Book 1",
        };
        var newBook = await repo.CreateBook(book);
    }
```

In the unit test method, if I don't specify a Id for a book object, it will throw an error saying the object with Id = 1000 has already been tracked by another entity.

Here is my reasoning:

(1) When I created Author test data, it created a number of books for each author. The books were created without specifying a Id since the field is Identity column for the SQL table.

(2) Then, I created my book test data with Id specified. The test data was created successfully.

(3) During the unit test, the system seems confused to pick up next available Id.

Is there a way to fix the problem without specifying a Id?

The unit test works well for netcore 2.1. After the unit test was converted to net core 3.1, the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the definition of your Book class to something like:

```
public class Book {
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set;} 
}
```

You could add additional Books by generating a new guid on the fly using:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Then when you create your new Book simply call g.ToString() to get the underlying value and assign it to the Id property. Of course you would also have to change the structure of your back-end database table to support this.

Comment: I am currently using a utility function to assign the Id when creating a book in my testing. I am trying to find a solution without specifying a Id.

Comment: @user3097695 By modifying that function to specify the ID as the result of a Guid.NewGuid() method call, you wouldn't need to manually specify an Id as the system will generate a new Guid each time the method is called.

Comment: We cannot change the definition of Id since the database was in production for a while. There is no problem for  actual API calls, but it only affects unit tests. I need to find the deep reasons behind the behaviors.

Comment: OK, perhaps you could use a helper function to select the max value of ID from your database and simply increment it by 1 for the new ID?

Comment: I am already doing that for unit test. I think there may be a bug in the NetCore 3.1. I don't think I need to add the Id. The system should automatically add a next available Id.

Answer (score 0):

Think how this works .... you're telling your system to create a book with id 1000. you run your method, now a book with id 1000 exists in the database. Then you run the method again and it fails because obviously your book with id 1000 is still in the database.

Next, you mock your database layer and create an entity with ID 1000 and you never get rid of it. The next time you run your method, you will probably get entity tracking issues.

This thing that you call a test, is not actually a test because there is no assert, you're not checking anything, thus it's not a test.

This is all very complicated and bound to create hair pulling issues. What you are trying to do tells me that you really want integration tests not unit tests.

If you want unit tests, I'd say take EF out of them and focus on real functionality like business rules etc.

Having integration tests is not a bad thing, but if you create real data, at the end of call, you should also clean it up.

An actual integration test would look like this:

1. create test book in db
2. issue a get and check the data is exactly what you expect using proper Assert statements between your expected data and actual data.

so:

1. create book with 1000
2. check the result of the call
3. load book with id 1000 from database
4. use asserts to check the things you care about
5. delete book with id 1000 and all related data from database

That's a normal flow for an integration test.

Typically, when you create data, you should not tell your database what id to use, let it insert the record and tell you what the unique id is. This takes care of a number of issues including multiple calls at the same time. Do not use the max function on the column to work out the next id, that has concurrency issues.

Depending on your system, it might be better to mark your id field in db as identity and auto-increment and then your ORM can see that and your layers will change so now you don't specify an id when trying to create something.

There are situations where you must specify an ID however, in which case an option would be to use something like a uniqueidentifier, specifically a GUID. That one has a very low chance of collision.

I would say, think what are you trying to test. Yes you can mock your repos etc, but if you mock them, then what are you testing? if you want to test that your items are created properly then you need to go all the way to the database because no mocking will help you with that. You might use an in-memory database as well, to speed things up and not actually touch the real database.

But the fact remains that unit tests are about functionality, checking data transformations etc. The less mocking you can do the better, it makes your tests maintainable especially when you refactor your code.

Also, try to avoid your ORM if you can, think of things in a functional way. 
Here is some data, I am calling this method, I should be getting this result. That would be appropriate for a unit test.

Comment: You have a valid point. I guess what I was trying to ask is why there is a different behavior between NetCore 2.1 and NetCore 3.1.